# Unable to UPDATE record in Database from form

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

I have a form which i am posting data to a database. I want it to update the record where sku=sku, I have never done this before so i have read up on this and tried various ways but they have not worked. here is what i have tried so far.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$hostname_conn = "host address";
$database_conn = "database";
$username_conn = "username";
$password_conn = "password";
$conn = mysql_connect($hostname_conn, $username_conn, $password_conn) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 

    mysql_select_db("bi_social", $conn);

    $sqlCmd = sprintf("UPDATE table2 SET sku2=%s sku=%s WHERE sku='%s'", 
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["sku"]),
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["sku2"]),
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["sku3"]));

    //echo $sqlCmd;
    //die();    

    mysql_query($sqlCmd);

    mysql_close($conn);
}

?>
<form method="post">
            <div class="large-3 columns">
<input name="sku" type="text" id="sku" placeholder="sku" value="<?=$_GET["sku"]?>"/>
            </div>
            <div class="large-3 columns">
<input name="sku2" type="text" id="sku2" placeholder="sku2" value="<?=$_GET["sku2"]?>"/>
            </div>
            <div class="large-3 columns">
<input name="sku3" type="text" id="sku3" placeholder="sku3" value="<?=$_GET["sku3"]?>"/>
            </div>
            <div class="large-3 columns">
    <input class="alert button" name="submit" type="submit" value="MATCH!"/>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I am not sure what i have done to make it not work i can though insert in to the database but updating does not work. Where am i going wrong and how do i fix this. Thanks Ryan

Comment: You are trying to update two things in one statement.. I'm not sure that's even possible. Anyway, the query is wrong. What is your error message?

Comment: @RensGroenveld I don't get one and it doesn't post to the database

Comment: If something goes wrong you should always get an error. Perhpas your error statements aren't passed through to your output. Try putting the next line: error_reporting(E_ALL); at the top of your script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a comma in update statement. The update statement should look something like this:

```
UPDATE table2 SET sku2='%s', sku='%s' WHERE sku='%s'
```

Comment: Thanks so much this worked i know see where i went wrong.  by not putting all of my %s in '' and missing the comma.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$sqlCmd = sprintf("UPDATE table2 SET sku3=%s, sku2=%s WHERE sku='%s'", 
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["sku3"]),
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["sk2"]),
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["sku"]));
```

OR,

```
$sqlCmd = "update table2 set sku3 = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sku3'])."', sku2 = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sku2'])."' where sku = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sku'])."'";
```

Comment: Hi @Niloy Saha I tried this and it has not worked Not sure why.

Comment: use the second query and let me know

Comment: Hi i tried this one too but it didn't work. But i have now found my answer and where i went wrong, Thanks for the help, Ryan